# How do I use QuaZip to extract multiple files?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, zip, quazip

I have the below code to move through a list of the folders and files in a zip archive creating them as I goes (also creating paths for files if not created yet).

The application crashes when I use `readData(char*, qint64)` to extract internal files data to stream it into a `QFile`. I don't think this is the right thing to use but it's all I've seen (in a very loose example on this site) and I also had to change the QuaZipFile.h to make the function public so I can use it (also hinting I shouldn't be using it).

It doesn't crash on the first file which has no contents but does after that. Here is the necessary code (ask if you need to see more):

```
QFile newFile(fNames);
newFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
QTextStream outToFile(&newFile);
char * data;
int len = file.readData(data, 100000000);
if(len > 0) {
    outToFile << data;
}
newFile.close();
```

It doesn't pass the `int len` line. What should I be using here? 
Note that the variable file is defined earlier pretty puch like this:

```
QuaZip zip("zip.zip");
QuaZipFile file(&zip);
...
zip.goToFirstFile();
...
zip.goToNextFile();
```

And the int passed to readData is a random number for the max data size.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for the crash is that you have not allocated any memory for your buffer, named `data`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I tried using different reads (readData, read, readLine) and found that this line works with no need for a data buffer:

```
outToFile << file.readAll();
```